# Mac Mail folders under TrueCrypt?

Tags: mac, email, truecrypt

I've looked around for information on how to do this but have not found any.

I would like to put a couple of email folders under a TrueCrypt volume while using Mac Mail but there does not seem to be a way to specify folders on a separate volume.

Comment: So it will work in theory, but does it work with Truecrypt? Or is this asking for trouble in general? I don't want to do whole-drive encryption, but to use OSX Mail, I might have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on any unix and thus I think might also work on MacOS:

- Quit your mail application.
- move the folder where the mail is stored to an eccrypted volumne.
- Place a symbolic link (ln -s ...) in the original place pointing to the new place.

You have to be careful to always mount the encrypted volume before you start the mail program as otherwise it will not find its files and may do anything weird.

Comment: I have done this before to put Mail's data store on a DMG file -- works great. If you put it on a DMSG, OS X will even open the DMG for you when it needs it. (Sometimes)